# Include History of Science and Mathematics in the list of sites to migrate to

Tags: feature-request, migration

Edit: this question is not a duplicate of the one that has been mentioned in the comments, as I am here suggesting a built-in feature to allow HSM as a potential site to migrate to within the reasons-for-closing section.

Recently, [one of my questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4185081/first-appearance-of-a-normal-distribution-table-in-a-publication)
was voted for closing with a reason that could apply to any question with the [math-history](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-history) tag: should be migrated to [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Since I'm not particularly against this migration (I simply had never heard of HSM upon asking the question), I tried to close the question myself, yet I couldn't because as of right now, you can choose the site to migrate to only from a list of three, and HSM is not one of them (see below). I think it should, even though HSM is still beta, as it will save time and as there is every reason to believe that HSM will flourish and become a full site.

[image]

Comment: This request has been made before here, for various other forums, but denied.  Search for the other instances.

Comment: @GEdgar The question you are referring to here is different, here I am suggesting a built-in way to indicate HSM as a potential site to migrate to.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate of the linked question. The linked question is from 6 years ago and is about moderators actively *not* migrating questions - times seem to have changed and we now migrate questions, and the question here asks: "can we make this easier?"

Comment: I have inquired about this before (I don't remember the destination site), where the destination site was a beta site, and the reply I got was that, in general, the devs preferred not to add a site that might disappear as a built-in destination for migration. Perhaps an interim solution would be to mention HSM in the tag info for [tag:math-history]. I've just looked, and it is mentioned there.

Comment: Thanks, @robjohn!  I have wondered the same about matheducators.se, which is also still beta.  I'll check with the education tag, and consider mentioning in the tag, "for questions related to math education, please consider asking on.... "

Comment: @ArnaudMortier  If you have interests in History of Science and Math, I would encourage you to participate there, as well.  Beta sites often have a solid core of users, but they remain Beta until user-ship (questions and answers) pick up.  Just like users can earn privileges, Proposed sites in Area 51 earn privileges by meeting milestones.

Answer (score 6):

For a question with no answers/comments, you (the poster of the question) can delete the question here and then ask on the other forum.

For a question with answers/comments (that you want to keep), flag the moderators and ask that it be migrated.

Questions older than 60 days, even the moderators cannot migrate.

Comment: This answer is useful (+1) but the point of my suggestion stands.

Answer (score 6):

In the last 90 days there was a single migration from here to HSM, and even looking in the list of migrated questions further back, one finds not only five questions were migrated in the duration of 2021.

As such it seems that the best way to proceed is to either advise the OP to delete and post the local copy; or flag for a moderator to do it. It is true that we are quite busy these days with the Enforcement of Quality Standards, but one flag in three months is something we can handle.

Comment: For comparison, can you also provide statistics for migrations to [stats.se] and [physics.se], if it's not too much trouble?

Comment: There is a possibility that adding this option will increase the number of such migrations (as people do not necessarily know HSM exists, or that migration-via-flagging is an option). Is it possible to have a "test period" where this option is available for 6 months? (Although I understand this all might be wrapped up in a ball of impenetrable admin so without stronger evidence there is no point in trying.)

Comment: In the last 90 days: we sent 3 questions to Physics, two were sent back; 15 to CV with 1 rejected.

Comment: @user1729 it's a priori clear that it's not worth it. It's not really useful for any site at all. See the numbers Asaf gave.